# mypy error on incompatible type SupportsIndex for list.__imul__

Tags: python, mypy

I am subclassing `list` with a definition for `__imul__()`.

```
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import SupportsIndex


class CustomList(list):
    def __imul__(self, n: SupportsIndex) -> CustomList:
        return super().__imul__(n)
```

mypy 0.910 with Python 3.9.2 raises an error that the argument type is incompatible.

> customlist.py:8: error: Argument 1 to "__imul__" of "list" has incompatible type "SupportsIndex"; expected "int"

This doesn't make sense to me. `__imul__()` definitely accepts a `SupportsIndex` argument. Per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types):

> 6. The value *n* is an integer, or an object implementing `__index__()`.

Is this a bug in mypy? Is there a way to resolve this error without adding a local ignore?